# PostgreSQL | Al realizar ALTER TABLE de una tabla no realiza el cambio correspondiente

Tags: django, postgresql

Necesito cambiar el nombre de algunas tablas de modelos de la base de datos de PostgreSQL (una aplicación que se llamaba "installation" llamarla "element"), pero tras ejecutar la siguiente orden, no queda el cambio guardado.
¿Qué sucede?

`ALTER TABLE installation_installation RENAME TO element_element`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecución:

```
dbaguas2=# ALTER TABLE <installation>_installation RENAME TO <element>_element
dbaguas2-# █
```

(No devuelve ningún error, pero no hace la modificación pertinente)

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Solo te hace falta agregar el `;` al final de tu query:

```
dbaguas2=# ALTER TABLE <installation>_installation RENAME TO <element>_element
dbaguas2-# ;
ALTER TABLE
```

> `ALTER TABLE` significa que se pudo renombrar con éxito

Esto pasa porque muchas sentencias son muy largas y es más fácil leerlas con saltos de linea y para permitir eso la terminal espera a que termines con `;`

Comment: Vaya, tienes razón. De todos modos me devuelve el siguiente error tras ejecutarlo con el ";" que había olvidado: ERROR:  relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE django_content_type SET app_label='<element>' WHERE a...

Comment: En ese caso puedes ejecutar `dbaguas2=# \d` (este comando no necesita `;`) para mostrar las tablas en la columna donde dice `name`. Las columnas que te aparecen son las columnas que puedes renombrar.